# How do you setup a Docker swarm on Raspberry Pis with one external (USB) storage device?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, docker-swarm, cloud-storage

I have a set of Raspberry Pi 3s connected to my network and I started with Raspian Lite and installed Docker on all of them.

On the first machine I run:
`docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.1.50`

On the rest of them I run the generated command:
`docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-abc... 192.168.1.50:2377`

Okay cool I have a swarm! The first Pi has a USB external HDD attached to it.  I want to run containers that will use the data on this external storage device.

1. How can I share the storage device to the entire swarm?
2. Or how can I force containers to run on the Pi with the attached storage device?
3. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you read the volumes documentation? That could be a way to manage persistent data storage.

Comment: @RichArt, thank you for the response. I have used docker with persistent data storage and I am familiar with how that works, but I don't see much in the documentation on how to integrate volumes with swam.